# Verified phone number is never recorded

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are in the process of creating our first B2C policies. One of our requirements is for new users to enter a MFA phone number and verify it, and record it in the user profile. We copied the example XML almost as-is, but clearly we did something wrong since, no matter how many times a user logs in, the phone number is never recorded in the profile and has to be re-entered and re-verified every time.

These are the relevant **TechnicalProfile** entries:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
  <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
    <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer"/>
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA"/>
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId"/>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber"/>
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPhoneNumberEntered" PartnerClaimType="newPhoneNumberEntered"/>
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true"/>
    </InputClaims>
<PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber"/>
  </PersistedClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

And these are the **OrchestrationStep** entries that refer to them:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
    <Value>newUser</Value>
    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify"/>
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
    <Value>newPhoneNumberEntered</Value>
    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId"/>
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

We did try varying, and removing, the **Preconditions** element from step 8, which had no effect at all. We've been over these a dozen times, and whatever it is we did wrong, we just don't see it. Why is the verified phone number not being written?

Comment: Did you find the issue with this? I'm hitting similar. Looking in the AppInsight logs, I can see that `newPhoneNumberEntered` is set to false at the point of step 8, even though I did enter a phone number!

Comment: Eventually we threw out what we had done and started over, and now this is working, but I cannot say what the difference is. The relevant parts of the redone policy look essentially the same as what I posted here, so I can only assume that the difference is somewhere else in our configuration. I wish I could be more helpful

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got it working in the end. I'm not using that `newPhoneNumberEntered` value anymore. I have my own claim which made more sense in my usecase to use in the preconditions.

Answer (score 0):

Update the precondition in OrchestrationStep 7 to below which will check if MFA is enabled and check the phone number on the record to verify further.

```
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
```

Comment: Alas, that change makes no difference. We still have to enter and verify a phone number every time, that does not get recorded in the user record.